# OpenSSH Connection Timed Out Issue

Tags: linux, centos, openssh

I am using Linux CentOS8 distribution. Openssh 8.0 installed on this server. When I try to connect via SSH to this server, connection timed out happens. I got a tcpdump and tcpdump shows that SSH request reaches to the server. I couldn't overcome this issue. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Is the firewall configured to allow ingress traffic on port 22? Is the SSH server listening on 22?

Comment: Firewall is configured to let SSH connection flow and OpenSSH works with default settings except 'PermitRootLogin yes'.

Comment: You checked that the SSH daemon is running, yes?

Comment: Yes. It is working. Even, I reinstalled openssh in case of program malfunction

Comment: It is easier to read pasted text instead of an image of your screen into a question. Also, since your problem is with ssh, it would be helpful to show your ssh command and output, consider also increasing the verbosity, ie `ssh -vv ...`